# Gaming GPUs and TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I went through the MNIST tutorial with conv nets and during the training -for the first time- felt the need to use a GPU. I have a **Geforce GTX 830M** on my laptop and was wondering if I could use it with tensorflow?

Should I invest the time to try to get it working or start searching for a low cost GPU with the right requirements?

[*I've been reading about very expensive and highly specialized equipment like the nvidia Digits, equipment's with half precision, etc.*]

Answer (score 4):

Looking at [this chart](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) the 830M has 5.0 compute capability, so in theory you'll be able to run TensorFlow (which requires 3.5). In practice you'll often hit problems with low memory on laptop GPUs, so you'll likely want to graduate to a desktop to do serious work, but it's a good way to get started.